# How to prevent" ## re-encoding from UTF-8" comment from being included into the PDF generated by markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am generating an R-markdown PDF. I am suppressing all code through `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)` and x table comments through `options(xtable.comment = FALSE)` , however, one comment from my `read.spss("~/anes.sav", to.data.frame = T)` which reads `## re-encoding from UTF-8`is still being included into my PDF. How do I prevent this comment from printing into my PDF?

Comment: try `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)`

Comment: Sometimes it is convenient to turn off messages, warnings or errors for individuals chunks only. This way you are alerted of possible errors.